# spring autowire 2 beans found exception

Tags: spring

i have a problem with spring autowire feature which found two beans with the same type, but in fact i only have one bean and the interface that this bean is implementing.

In applicationContext.xml i have these lines:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.vs.services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.vs.dao"/>  
<context:annotation-config/> 

<bean id="intermedDao" class="xxx.vs.dao.yyy.IntermedDaoImpl" />
```

and :

```
package xxx.vs.dao.abs.yyy;    
public interface IntermedDao extends GenericDao<Intermed> {
    // methods here
}
```

---

```
package xxx.vs.dao.yyy;    
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public class IntermedDaoImpl extends GenericInboundDaoImpl<Intermed> implements IntermedDao {
    // methods here
}
```

---

```
package xxx.vs.services.yyy;
@Service
@Transactional
public class IntermedServiceImpl implements IntermedService {

    @Autowired
    IntermedDao dao;

    public IntermedDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(IntermedDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }    
}
```

with this config i get:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'intermedServiceImpl': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: xxx.vs.dao.abs.yyy.IntermedDao xxx.vs.services.yyy.IntermedServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No unique bean of type [xxx.vs.dao.abs.yyy.AgentDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [intermedDaoImpl, intermedDao]
```

does this happens because i scan the packages that contains the interfaces that my DAO`s classes are implementing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you've both explicitly declared a bean:

```
<bean id="intermedDao" class="xxx.vs.dao.yyy.IntermedDaoImpl" />
```

as well as declaring a `@Repository` to be picked up by component scanning:

```
@Repository
public class IntermedDaoImpl
```

You need to do one or the other, not both.  I suggest deleting the `<bean>`.

Note that the error message:

> expected single matching bean but found 2: [intermedDaoImpl, intermedDao]

Mentions the conflicting beans. The first one is your `@Repository`, where the name of the bean is auto-generated from the classname; the second one is your `<bean>`.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating two instances of your dao bean, one in the XML and again using `@Repository` annotation.

Look closely at the error:

```
expected single matching bean but found 2: [intermedDaoImpl, intermedDao]
```

Either only create one bean instance (either in XML or annotation-wise), or use `@Qualifier` when wiring it to specify which one to use.

Comment: indeed, after i have removed the xml bean everything was ok. Thanks.