# Spring more than one bean of type: crash early

Tags: java, spring, autowired

When I load a webpage in my Spring web application, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than one bean of type [com.Car] found, you have to specify the name of the bean
```

How can I force Spring to detect this problem at startup?

Please do note that I know how to solve the problem on itself (e.g. removing one of the two definitions) 
I just want to be sure that there aren't any other cases that I will not find before opening every single webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring autowire 2 beans found exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530017/spring-autowire-2-beans-found-exception)

Comment: Did you specify your configuration to be evaluated lazily, by any chance? Failing as soon as an ambiguity is detected is already how Spring behaves by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BeanPostProcessor which keeps track of number of instances created for each bean definition in the application context. THis will throw an exception for bean types that you want to restrict and will halt the container initialization. Hence you can detect the errors earlier

```
    public class DuplicateBeanDetectionBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor{

    private Map<Class<?> , Boolean> beanTypeFound = new HashMap<Class<?> , Boolean>();

    private Set<Class<?> typesToRestrictToOneInstance = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException{
    return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException{
    Set<Class<?>> restrictedTypesForBean = findRestrictedTypesForInstance(bean);
    if(!restrictedTypeForBean.isEmpty() && typeAlreadyFound(bean , restrictedTypesForBean)){
       throw new IllegalStateException("Bean of type : " + restrictedTypeForBean + " already found in the application context";
    }
    return bean;
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> findRestrictedTypesForInstance(Object bean){
      Set<Class<?>> restrictedTypesForBean = hew HashSet<>();
      Class<?> superClass = bean.getClass();
    while(superClass != null){
       for(Class<?> restrictedType : typesToRestrictToOneInstance){
          if(restrictedType.isAssignableFrom(superClass){
               restrictedTypesForBean.add(restrictedType);
          }
       }
    }
    return restrictedTypesForBean;
    }

    private boolean typeAlreadyFound(Object bean , Set<Class<?>> restrictedTypesForBean){
    for(Class<?> restrictedTypeForBean : restrictedTypesForBean){
        if(beanTypeFound.get(restrictedTypeForBean)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
           beanTypeFound.set(restrictedTypeForBean , true);
        }
    }
    return false;
    }

    public void setTypesToRestrictToOneInstance(Set<Class<?>> typesToRestrictToOneInstance){
   this.typesToRestrictToOneInstance = typesToRestrictToOneInstance;
}
}
```

Add the BeanPostProcessor to your application context through suited to your configuration mechanism. Then set all types that you want to restrict